# How to remove extra months in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

[My Graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR3Mw.png)  I am making a graph in Rstudio, and I wanted my months chronologically from June to September

```
ggplot(data = MyData, aes(x= Date, y = Length, color = ID)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name)
```

I used scale_*x_*discrete, but it added all the months to my graph instead. How do I remove the extras?

Comment: `month.name` returns a vector of all 12 months, what you need is `month.name[6:9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there's a quick answer: month.name is an object with every month in the year. This is why even if you filter your MyData to only include months with Length data, your graph will continue to display placeholders for months without data

You should be able to create your own object writing out only those months with Length data to fix the x axis scaling

```
months_with_data <- c("June", 
                  "July",
                  "August", 
                  "September")
 MyData %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x= Date, y = Length, color = ID)) +
     geom_boxplot() 
     scale_x_discrete(limits = months_with_data)
```

Without having reproducible data, I can't know how you could use your data to do this more quickly. But it could look something like this

```
months_with_data <- unique(MyData$month)
```

The R language collective has resources to help with writing reproducible examples. Questions with reproducible examples might help you get quicker and more relevant answers.